# $\|AA^Tx\|_2\geq\sigma_1\|A^Tx\|_2$ with $\sigma_1$ being the smallest positive singular value of $A$?

Tags: matrices

Regarding the $\ell_2$-norm, we know that $$\|A^Tx\|_2\geq\sigma_0\|x\|_2,$$where $A$ is a matrix, $x$ is a column vector, and $\sigma_0$ is the smallest singular value of $A$.

Now consider $\|AA^Tx\|_2$. Is it true to conclude that $$\|AA^Tx\|_2\geq\sigma_1\|A^Tx\|_2,$$ where $\sigma_1$ is the smallest positive singular value of $A$ and is assumed to exist. Obviously this is true when all the singular values are positive. The case that shall be considered is that $A$ has $0$ and at least one positive singular values, i.e., $\sigma_0=0$ and $\sigma_1>0$.

I think it correct, but haven't got a proof. If possible, please leave the idea proof.

Thanks.

Comment: $A$ and $A^T$ have the same positive singular values. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Can you give some ideas of proof? Thanks.

Comment: Use the singular value decomposition of $A$. The $\ell_2$ norm is invariant wrt. orthogonal transformation

Comment: @user251257 you misunderstood; $\sigma_1$ is the smallest *non-zero* singular value.

Comment: Well, I still got stuck in the details. Let $A=U\Sigma V^T$. Then $\|AA^Tx\|_2 = \|U\Sigma V^TV\Sigma^T U^Tx\|_2=\|\Sigma\Sigma^TU^Tx\|_2$. Meanwhile, we have $\sigma_1\|A^Tx\|_2 = \sigma_1\|\Sigma^TU^Tx\|_2$. Then what follows? Thanks.

Comment: Possibly helpful: Note that $\|A^Tx\|^2 = x^TAA^Tx \leq \|x^T\| \|AA^Tx\|$.  So,
$$
\|AA^Tx \| \geq\frac{\|A^Tx\|^2}{\|x\|}
$$
if $x\neq 0$

Comment: Your inequality certainly holds when $x \in \ker(A^T)^\perp = \overline{\operatorname{im}(A)}$

Comment: Thanks. I am considering it's true for any real $A$ and $x$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: oh right. my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write $\sigma_{\min+}$ instead of $\sigma_1$, as the usual convention is to index singular values in descending order, i.e. $\sigma_1=\sigma_\max$ and $\sigma_n=\sigma_\min$ if the size of $A$ is $n\times m$.

Anyway, the answer to your question should be obvious. Let $A=USV^T$ be a singular value decomposition. For any vector $x\in\mathbb R^n$, let $y=U^T x$. Then the inequality $\|AA^Tx\|_2\geq\sigma_{\min+}\|A^Tx\|_2$ can be rewritten as $\|USS^Ty\|_2\geq\sigma_1\|VS^Ty\|_2$. Since orthogonal matrices preserve Euclidean norms, the inequality can be further rewritten as $\|SS^Ty\|_2\geq\sigma_{\min+}\|S^Ty\|_2$. You may continue from here.

Comment: Thanks. The remaining part is easy.